# Auto logout linux regardless of idle time

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

(Ubuntu) Hello, so am looking for a way to have my computer automatically logout in 30 minutes regardless if the system has been idle. Figure write a script then have it auto run on login?

Comment: This works if you're on a tty: `(sleep 30m; kill -9 $$) &`

Comment: You shouldn't need the `-9`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to program your GNU / Linux system to shut down automatically you just write the following in terminal (alt + F2):

$ sudo shutdown -h +30

What does this command do?

sudo shutdown -h (halt) +30 (at 30 minutes)

The +30 can change it for the number of minutes you want your computer to turn off.

If you have panic to the terminal can download this Gshutddown applet that is in the repositories, just go to System, Administration, Synaptic Package Manager and there you are looking for Gshutdown and double click to install.

Gshutdown is more configurable, you can have it shut down or reboot the computer after a certain time or at a certain time.

Even so I still prefer the simplicity of the simple command above.

Comment: Thank you, your first suggestion works great, any idea how I can auto run this program on start up? Should I save it as a .sh  file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, right to create a script with the code in a file and perform the following steps.

Once we know how runlevel work, we proceed to explain how to run a script or program at system startup.

1) Give script permission.

```
#sudo chmod -x myscript.sh
```

2) Copy the script to the /etc/init.d/ folder

```
#sudo cp myscript.sh /etc/init.d/
```

3) We make it a daemon, that is, it is executed at the beginning of the session.

```
#sudo update-rc.d myscript.sh defaults
```

If you want to delete the script, you must write

```
#sudo update-rc.d -f myscript.sh remove
```

Good luck!
Hope it has fit